# UIPanGesture or TouchesMoved moving Sprites. What is the best method?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, gesture

I have what is becoming a fairly complex SpriteKit based app, all made programmatically.
I am moving a number of arrays of SpriteNodes around and have two possible methods to achieve this. Using either Touches Moved function or I can use the UIPanGestureRecognizer to do the same thing in pretty much the same way.

But which is the best way to go? I also have lots of other UI gestures going on like Rotate,Pinch and double tap and I'm worried about conflicting code.

Is it bad practice to combine them ? (I don't mean both methods at the same time - I mean having some touches read by Gestures and others with Touches functions)
Do I have more control or precision with Pan over Touches?
I feel, now that I have it mostly working better to only use Gestures if possible 
but what is the best practice?

Some of my code. I have up to maybe 40-50 nodes stored in arrays being moved around.

In touches moved:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                    for touch in touches{

                        let location = touch.location(in: self)

                        if numberOfBalls >= 0 {
                            for i in 0...(numberOfBalls) {

                                if ballBloqArray[i].contains(location) {

                                    ballBloqArray[i].position = location

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if numberOfBoxes >= 0 {
                            for i in 0...(numberOfBoxes) {
                                if boxBloqArray[i].contains(location) {
                                    boxBloqArray[i].physicsBody?.pinned = false
                                    boxBloqArray[i].position = location
                                    boxBeingMoved = i
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


    }
```

and using PanGesture:

```
 let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.tappedOnce(sender:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
        panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true

@objc func tappedOnce(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began{


    }

    if sender.state == .changed {
        var location = sender.location(in: self.view)
        location = self.convertPoint(fromView: location)

        print("Single tap")
        print(location)
        if numberOfBalls >= 0 {
            for i in 0...(numberOfBalls) {

                if ballBloqArray[i].contains(location) {

                    ballBloqArray[i].position = location

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no best,  they both have strengths and weaknesses.

The important thing is to stay consistent.  Do not combine the two.  Pick one method or the other.

Personally, I would go with the Gestures.  It allows you to separate the code, and gives you a very clear definition of what is being performed when a touch is moved.